# Lightbox with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox2

So I am trying to use Lightbox2 on my application. I installed the gem and followed all the steps, but having trouble figuring out where to call it in the application.

This is my post index

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="profuploads">
  <div id="posts" class="transitions-enabled">
   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <div class="box panel panel-default">
    <%= link_to image_tag(post.image.url(:medium)), post %>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <strong><%= post.user.username if post.user %></strong><br/>
     <%= post.description %>
     <% if post.user == current_user %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my post show

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading center">
    <%= image_tag @post.image.url, height: '300' %>
   </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    <p><strong><%= link_to(@post.user.username.capitalize, user_path(@post.user.id)) if @post.user %></strong></p>
    <p><%= @post.description %></p>

    <div class="votes">
      <strong>VIEWS</strong>
    <%= @post.hits %>
      <div class="votes">
      <%= link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :put do%>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up glyphicon-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="badge"><%= @post.get_upvotes.size %></span>
          </button>
          <%end%>
          </div>
    <% if @post.user == current_user %>
     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

With Lightbox do I need to just git rid of my post show page altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox is a javascript library which needs proper html markup in order to do it's work. Your `show` view looks good except it does not include the markup Lightbox looks for.

From [Lightbox Getting Started](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) guide:

> Add a data-lightbox attribute to any image link to enable Lightbox. For the value of the attribute, use a unique name for each image. For example:
>   Image #1

When Lightbox initializes, it looks for any image tags that contain `data-lightbox` attribute and hooks its handlers to them. You need to provide this attribute:

```
<%= image_tag @post.image.url, height: '300', "data-lightbox" => @post.image.url %>
```

This should make Lightbox pick up your images.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was missing that data-lightbox call. I just didn't know where to put it. I tried this and still nothing. My normal show page shows

Comment: My question is does Lightbox2 just kinda zoom in on the pic and not actually go to the pic's own URL?

Comment: Please show the resulting html after this fragment renders.